# Making a Chrome extension to read custom file types

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, file-extension

I've been working on a compiler for a custom conditional formating language, and I want to be able to open files in my language in Chrome by double-clicking on them in File Explorer (I am on Windows).

I know that I can make a .exe that will open my file type (.uif), but that would only work for opening outside of chrome and I need `<a href="file.uif">` tags to work as well.

I already have the compiler as a JavaScript file, but I'm not sure how to make a chrome extension control how files are read or if it can even be done.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I just had to set chrome as the default browser for `.uif`.

Then, I made a content script for my chrome extension which interprets `.uif` files and translates it to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to make a script or executable like .bat, .vba, or .exe to open it in chrome. You could make a bat or vba file that you can open the file with that sends the file data to chrome and your extension. Not sure if this will help but its worth a shot! Good luck!

Comment: What about <a> tags linking to my files from in the browser? can I link them to my .exe somehow too?

Comment: @marcthird that should work if you get the correct file path to your exe

Comment: I guess that might work if I set the defualt app for `.uif` to my exe, but then when I clicked on `<a>` tags it would just download the file